# How to connect AWS EC2 private IP with filezilla

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am currently working on an AWS EC@ LINUX AMI. I have a private IP. Is it possible to access that private IP with filezilla to transfer files. i am unable to do so.

Comment: It's called private for a reason.

Comment: I understand that, so is there any way I can use ANY GUI for file transfer. Currently I am using ssh to a jumpserver & from there to private ip.

Comment: use ssh -i private-key instance-name@ip-address.

Comment: You can use VPN connectivity to get connect with private subnets. otherwise you should have to use public IP for that’s instances.

Comment: private key means which you have downloaded while creating the instance

Comment: I think private-key means *.pem file

Comment: @raju yes use that

Answer (score 0):

For access an EC2 machine with private IP, you need to setup your own VPN server. If you already have VPN setup in your AWS cloud then you just need to install a VPN client and login with your credential and you will be able to access EC2 machine or transfer files using filezilla with private IP too. I am assuming that you haven't setup VPN server. you may use AMI of OPENVPN from AWS market place for setup VPN. Below is the good link for getting start.

https://docs.openvpn.net/how-to-tutorialsguides/virtual-platforms/amazon-ec2-appliance-ami-quick-start-guide/

After complete this you have to install OPENVPN in your machine and after Login with your credentials your will able to access your EC2 instance with private IP.

Below is the link for install OPENVPN in Ubuntu machine. For different operating system you can explore site.

https://docs.openvpn.net/getting-started/how-to-install-openvpn-as-software/

OPENVPN is one of the alternative, you can use other also as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

Using 2 ways you can do this

1. Create a bastion host which will connect to the private instance
2. Using a port forwarding means tunnelling.

If you are using bastion host for connecting private ec2 instance then this steps will be useful

Using Filezilla to transfer files to a private ec2 instance through a bastion host:-

Note: Keep Pem file same of bastion host and private ec2 instance.

1. Open terminal or cmd(linux terminal i.e gitbash)
2. we are connecting to the AWS EC2 instance with one terminal command.

ssh -N -L 1234:<private_instance_ip or Private_DNS>:22 -i <Pem_File> @<Bastion_host_public_ip>

e.g.
ssh -N -L 1234: ip-171-12-21-208.us-east-1.compute.internal:22 -i app_prod.pem ubuntu@ec2-31-92-123-22.us-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com

Note: - For the first time when you enter this command it will ask for Are you sure you want to continue connecting - yes

3.Keep this terminal or cmd open.
If you close this session then the connection is broken

4.Open “FileZilla” application and on “Edit” section -> Click on “Settings”

5.On “Settings” page -> Click on “SFTP” and add PEM file of ec2 instance and click on “OK”

6.Add below entries:-

Host:-    127.0.0.1 or sftp://127.0.0.1
Username:-  <your_user>
Password:- Keep empty
Port:- 1234

7.Click on Quick Connect.
Once the connection is established then you can easily transfer files from local to private instance.

See- scp-to-transfer-files-to-a-private-ec2-instance-through-a-bastion-host

https://www.davidbegin.com/using-scp-to-transfer-files-to-a-private-ec2-instance-through-a-bastion-host/